# Trying to add a mouseover effect to this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, tabs, mouseover

Hello am trying to add a mouse over effect to this code but ive been unsuccessful in doing so, Any help would be great... Am not sure if you will need anymore info but if so I can add anything you need

The problem I have is that when I over over the Tab's I can click the text and it highlights it all :( am after the normal mouse over effect if that can be done

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function init(){
    var stretchers = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    var toggles = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
    var myAccordion = new fx.Accordion(
        toggles, stretchers, {opacity: false, height: true, duration: 600}
    );
    //hash functions
    var found = false;
    toggles.each(function(h3, i){
        var div = Element.find(h3, 'nextSibling');
            if (window.location.href.indexOf(h3.title) > 0) {
                myAccordion.showThisHideOpen(div);
                found = true;
            }
        });
        if (!found) myAccordion.showThisHideOpen(stretchers[0]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at mouseenter/mouseleave stuff in mootools (assuming that's what you're using)

On a side note, you can also do "var stretchers = $$('.box');" if you are indeed using moo

Comment: Hi Am very very new to the way JS works, Yes in this zip I found two files with moo in them moo.fx.js and moo.fx.pack.js. There was also prototype.lite.js

Comment: Honestly, mootools comes with a nice accordion component, and is pretty decently documented.  I'd just use whatever they've got there if it will do the trick for you (check out the more docs on mootools.net)

Answer (score 0):

To add a mouseover effect in jquery, try it like this:

```
$('#your id / .your class').bind('mouseover', function() {
    alert('hello world');//YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

I don't see any mouseover events in your code, check the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/):

Comment: Can I add that to the above JS?

Comment: Judging by `var div = Element.find`, he's not using jQuery - so no, that won't work.